# Add colon to algorithm Caption after algorithm number

Tags: captions, algorithms, algorithmicx

If I typeset a simple algorithm using the algorithmicx package, say

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Bisection}
  \label{alg:1}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \Repeat
    \State $t\gets \frac{a+b}{2}$
    \State and so on...
  \Until{$f(t)>\epsilon$}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

the result looks similar to:

[image: compiled latex]

How do I add a colon behind the number of the algorithm, i.e. i would like to get

**Algorithm A.1:** Bisection

My first idea was to redefine `thealgorithm` as

```
%\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}:}
```

However, in this case every time I reference an algorithm I also gain the colon. Bad idea. Of course I could redefine the command before and after the algorithm environment or create my own environment that encapsulates `algorithm` and makes the corresponding definitions. But is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load the `caption` package and define

```
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelsep=colon}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelsep=colon}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Bisection}
  \label{alg:1}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \Repeat
    \State $t\gets \frac{a+b}{2}$
    \State and so on...
  \Until{$f(t)>\epsilon$}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]